# How to open an activity on top of the main activity layout using intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to create an intent in MainActivity that will launch CompassActivity.

Both classes share a common layout activity_main, but use different parts of it.

Here is the intent I currently have in MainActivity which is supposed to open the CompassActivity.java class file but doesn't.

```
public void startCompass(View v)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, CompassActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

What I have tried:

- Altering androidmainfest.xml.
- Changing the intent itself.
- Changing the SDK version.

Comment: What do you mean by `different parts of it`?

Comment: Manish, I mean that MainActivity uses button, and CompassActivity uses pointer. Different parts of the activity_main.xml file.

Comment: Why do you start a new intent within the same layout? You can do it all in one actvity?

Comment: I want the intent to open a class file that will manipulate a view in my activity_main.xml layout file.

Comment: Folks, this WILL work (you can start multiple different Activities with the same layout.xml file).  Not optimal.  What is the issue you have with opening the Intent (that is the problem)

Comment: The way of approach is wrong @officialasim! It will work obviously but that is not recommended. Better you can try Fragments or implement it as separate activity and check. But still your approach also should work. I have tried the same way u implemented. Its working for me. Can you post your xml?

Comment: My activity_main.xml is not the issue here. The issue is that the intent isn't opening the CompassActivity.class file as it should.

Comment: Where are you calling startCompass method? In OnClickListener of button through java code or xml? If you're calling from xml have you set the tag android:onClick = "startCompass" ? Because I implemented your way and it worked! So trying to understand your way of implementation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is place the correct variables under the onCreate method and it should work fine.

Comment: This was the problem. The variables were misconstrued.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open an intent or do you just want to show/hide the different views you are using?

Instantiate your Views (findViewById) in your onCreate, then you can call view.setVisibility(View.GONE or View.VISIBILE) to hide or display your different views.

Bottom line, your views exist already on the main Activity (so no Intent needed to start another Activity) - you just need to control which views are visible at a particular time.

Comment: CompassActivity.java contains my compass code. It is required for the pointer to move according to the magnetic field. That's why I want the intent to open it from MainActivity.

Comment: Put that code in your Main Activity.  You are confused about how things work in the Android framework.  You could also convert your Compass to a Fragment (seems like the right solution for you) but this is an advanced topic and more complicated.